# Why is the HDRI reflection different and how do I control it?

Tags: camera, hdri, reflection

My objects have the same scale, but a different reflection area.

Even though the mesh is of similar size, the reflected area is different, so the result is different. I want to adjust the area reflected on the objects so that it is the same for all objects.

How can i control the environment reflections?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). You're viewing each object from a slightly different angle - hence the difference in reflections.

Comment: thanks. Those are front veiw

Answer (score 0):

When using perspective camera, the reflections will never match.
To preview the same reflections, you can use local collections.

1. Put each glasses into a different collection, but give them the same coordinates (like 0,0,0)
2. Open multiple viewports side by side
3. Go *View > Collections* and choose which one to show for each viewport

[image]